# How to add a comment using comment boxes in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am building an Access database for work. I have set up a report to open upon click for a certain record. So only the information of that record is to appear on the report. However, I would like to add a comment box in the report where you can add comments. The new comments are stamped and added to the previous comments already showing in the report. I was able to program the commenting function in a separate report. However, for the reports that show only specific records it won't work. I know it is because I have to somehow add each comment to my database, but I just can not figure out how to do it. I used the following code that I found online in another article. It works fine when your comments are not tied to a certain record.

```
Private Sub cmdAppendComment_Click()
If (IsNull(txtNewComment.Value)) Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a comment before clicking" & _
            "on the Append Comment button.")
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' These commented lines will never be reached:
  ' If (IsNull(txtComment.Value)) Then
  '   Table.tblmain.User_comment.Value = txtNewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
  '              VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  ' Else
    Table.tblmain.User_comment.Value = txtComment.Value & _
               vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               txtNewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
               VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  ' End If

  ' txtNewComment.Value = ""
  ' Use Null:
  txtNewComment.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: Commented out some lines that will not be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a form, not report, for this.

Bind this to the table, add the new comment to the existing comment bound to texbox, and save the record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but would you please elaborate more, I am new to vba and access. my background is C#. When you say "Bind this to the table," what do you mean exactly? I also honestly do not understand what you mean by "add the new comment to the existing comment bound to textbox." I apologize if my questions are stupid, but I've searched the internet high and low for an answer before asking my question

Comment: The question is not stupid, but you miss the basic understanding of Access and the philosophy behind which is very different from, say, WinForms and dotNet. So my best advice would be to browse for a developer's tutorial in Access; any decent tutorial will deal with tables and forms and code behind these.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, you pointed me in the right direction, I just used a form instead of report, bounded my "view" textbox to my table, modified my code a little bit, and voila, it worked like a charm.